# What is wrong with my implementation / build of Farseer Physics in that I can't call certain classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, farseer

My version of XNA: 4.0
My version of VS: 2010 Express
My version of Farseer: 3.5

I am attempting to implement the Farseer physics libraries into my XNA project. I downloaded the source code, and built the FarseerPhysics Xbox360 library as well as the DebugView Xbox360 library. I then attempted to add them to my new game solution by right clicking `references > add reference > and the corresponding .dll files.`

I then added the using statements at the top of my class so that I could potentially utilize the libraries.

`using FarseerPhysics.Dynamics;
using FarseerPhysics.Factories;
using FarseerPhysics.DebugView;`

I am not receiving errors with these imports, so my project seems to be finding the libraries. I also do not receive an error when instantiating the likes of `World world;`

However, when I attempt to use certain classes within these libraries, that's where my errors occur.

For example, attempting to use `ConvertUnits`, I receive the following error "The name ConvertUnits does not exist in the current context. My line of code is `floor.Position = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(240, 775);` I have verified that the ConvertUnits file has been included in the build of FarseerPhysics.

I am also receiving errors when attempting to use `DebugViewFlags.*`, with the same error message being displayed.

Am I missing a step in building / adding a reference / using both of these libraries?

Comment: in what namespace is ConvertUnits?

Comment: it seems that is under FarseerPhysics only, so you should have this too : using FarseerPhysics;

Comment: @elios264 I am such an idiot, thank you so much! Literally spent 2 hours building and rebuilding the libraries and didn't even think of `using FarseerPhysics;`

Answer (score 0):

with 3.x, FPE(Farseer Physics Engine) 
The ConvertUnits class can be found under Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 Samples XNA\Samples XNA\Samples XNA\ScreenSystem. ConvertUnits is a helper class that lets us switch between display units (pixels) and simulation units (MKS) easily.

This file can be downloaded here: http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/releases/view/64108

Original Post at: http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/247635

So you basically need to add the ConverUnits.cs file to your project, and you should be able to convert meters to pixels just fine :)

Comment: hey @Feek, the original post was copied from farseerphysics.codeplex.com and the stackexchange post you pointed to is copied from codeplex